# parsing a file using fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, getline

There is probably more issues at hand, but for now my problem is that when I compile and run this like so:

```
cc -o parser parser.c
./parser
```

I expect it to open a particular file, read from it, and parse it. However, it seems to expect me to provide input and I have to Ctrl-C to kill it. Am I using `fgets` wrong? I tried `getline()` with the same results. I added the `puts()` to make sure it was reading what I expected and it does. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE    *fp;
    char    buf[1024];
    char    *tmp, *pattern, *dir; 
    char    *skip, *p;
    char    *tok[5];
    char    **ap;
    size_t  sz = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    int i;
    int action = 0; // placeholder
    int fileinto = 1; // placeholder
    char    path[PATH_MAX] = "/home/edgar/.patfile";


    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen failed");
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';

        // skip comments
        for (skip = buf; *skip; ++skip) {
            if (*skip == '#') {
                *skip = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        // skip empty lines
        if (strlen(buf) == 0)
            continue;
        puts(buf); // debug only
        // make a copy
        tmp = strdup(buf);

        for (i = 0, ap = tok; ap < &tok[4] && (*ap = strsep(&tmp, " ")) != NULL; i++) {
            if (**ap != '\0')
                ap++;
        }

        while (i >= 0) {
           if(tok[i] == "match")
                pattern = tok[i + 1];
           if(tok[i] == "fileinto") {
                action = fileinto;
                dir = tok[i + 1];
           }
        }
   }
   free(tmp);
   fclose(fp);
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `while (i >= 0) { ... }` : This is an infinite loop. `i` is not updated in the loop.

Comment: Also `free(tmp);` : `tmp` is changed by `strsep`. `strcmp` instead of `==` is used to compare strings.

Comment: You might very well use a *contemporary* C standard and declare the variables at the first use. C99 has been a thing for 18 years. (You'd notice that there are unused variables).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I see what you mean about the loop.  How should I free(tmp) then?

Comment: Save it in advance.

Comment: @Antti They are remnants of figuring this out. They will be removed or used later. Thanks.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY like so: free_tmp = tmp = strdup(buf); free(free_tmp)

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Part of that process is eliminating the unnecessary — and unused variables are by definition unnecessary.  You should not post code on SO that has unused variables in it.  You can expect to get negative comments if you do — you should not expect those who you're asking to help you to wade through irrelevant code.

Comment: If the `fopen()` fails, you report as much, but then proceed to use the invalid `fp` just as if it was OK.   You should exit, or return, or otherwise ensure the invalid file stream handle is not used. This presumably isn't an immediate problem — you aren't seeing the error message and your program isn't crashing.